# How can Azure Open AI Service map subfields of an Edm.ComplexType field from an Azure Cognitive Search index?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search, azure-openai

I created an Azure Cognitive Search resource populated with the cosmosdb **hotels-sample** database from the Samples.

[image]

I created an index using the defaults (no cognitive skills, nor customization of index). So this is how my index looks like:

[image]

By using the Search explorer with the query "Albuquerque", this JSON document is returned.

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://myazurecognitiveendpoint.search.windows.net/indexes('hotels-sample-index')/$metadata#docs(*)",
  "value": [
    {
      "@search.score": 0.9808292,
      "HotelId": "20",
      "HotelName": "Travel Resort",
      "Description": "The Best Gaming Resort in the area.  With elegant rooms & suites, pool, cabanas, spa, brewery & world-class gaming.  This is the best place to play, stay & dine.",
      "Description_fr": "La meilleure station de jeux dans la région.  Avec des chambres et suites élégantes, piscine, Cabanas, Spa, brasserie & Gaming de classe mondiale.  C'est le meilleur endroit pour jouer, rester et dîner.",
      "Category": "Budget",
      "Tags": [
        "continental breakfast",
        "bar",
        "pool"
      ],
      "ParkingIncluded": false,
      "LastRenovationDate": "2014-10-31T00:00:00Z",
      "Rating": 4.2,
      "Location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -106.605949,
          35.1087
        ],
        "crs": {
          "type": "name",
          "properties": {
            "name": "EPSG:4326"
          }
        }
      },
      "Address": {
        "StreetAddress": "3400 Menaul Blvd NE",
        "City": "Albuquerque",
        "StateProvince": "NM",
        "PostalCode": "87107",
        "Country": "USA"
      },
      "Rooms": [
        {
          "Description": "Budget Room, 1 Queen Bed (City View)",
          "Description_fr": "Chambre Économique, 1 grand lit (vue sur la ville)",
          "Type": "Budget Room",
          "BaseRate": 72.99,
          "BedOptions": "1 Queen Bed",
          "SleepsCount": 2,
          "SmokingAllowed": false,
          "Tags": [
            "coffee maker"
          ]
        },
        ... more rooms
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Inspecting the document, I guess the indexer got it since Albuquerque is present on the **City** *subfield* of the **Address** *field* which is good.

Now, my goal was, to integrate the index as a data source in the Azure OpenAI Service Chat.

[image: data sources options]

[image: fields with no option to select subfields]

Using **HotelName**, **Description** and/or **Category** worked as expected.
But, when using **Address** I got this

[image: error on not searchable field]

Likewise, with **Tags** *field*, I get another error.

[image: error with a collection]

So, it seems complex fields and collection fields are not searchable even though the subfields are searchables.

```
{
      {
      "name": "Tags",
      "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": true,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": "en.microsoft",
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchConfiguration": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
      },
      "name": "Address",
      "type": "Edm.ComplexType",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "StreetAddress",
          "type": "Edm.String",
          "searchable": true,
          "filterable": false,
          "retrievable": true,
          "sortable": false,
          "facetable": false,
          "key": false,
          "indexAnalyzer": null,
          "searchAnalyzer": null,
          "analyzer": "en.microsoft",
          "normalizer": null,
          "dimensions": null,
          "vectorSearchConfiguration": null,
          "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
          "name": "City",
          "type": "Edm.String",
          "searchable": true,
...
}
```

The OpenAI wizard to load the data source does not have a dropdown to select the subfields individually.

1. Is there a way to select them?
2. Am I missunderstanding something with the index?

I also tried to add a "searchable": true option at the JSON index definition but it did not let me.

I expect to get a response from Azure OpenAI Service Chat with information about the document from Albuquerque.